# SPLIT_BUNDLE 52. Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies , what is the solution?

Tags: android

Issue found: Invalid Encryption Declaration on your Data safety form
We’ve detected discrepancies between how your app collects and shares user data and what was declared in your app’s Data safety form. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety form that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is required even if your app does not collect any user data.

You have declared that user data is encrypted in transit in your app’s Data safety form and we’ve detected unencrypted network traffic that may carry user data off device.

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 52: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: "http://atracking-auto.astrodsp.com"
About the Data safety section in Google Play User Data policy
All developers must complete a clear and accurate Data safety section for every app detailing collection, use, and sharing of user data. Your app must be in compliance with this policy. If your app continues to be non-compliant, your app may face additional enforcement actions in the future.

Please make changes to align your app’s Data safety form with the app’s behavior. This can be done by either:

Updating your form in Play Console to indicate that your app does not encrypt in transit; or
Encrypt the above traffic identified as unencrypted. Check out our guide for Network Security Best Practices
For helpful resources, you can:

Learn more about how to provide app privacy and security information for Google Play's Data safety section.
Watch the Google Play PolicyBytes - Data safety form walkthrough.
Check Google Play SDK Index to see if your SDK provider has shared a link to their data safety guidance. Review how any third-party code (such as third-party libraries or SDKs) in your app collects and shares user data.